# ReferenceError: Object prop not defined

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript:

```
var calc = {
    getMem: function(){
        return mem;
    },

    mem:0,

    add: function (a,b){
        mem =  a*b;
        return a*b;
    },
}
```

When I call

```
calc.getMem();
```

right after away I get a ReferenceError

However, when I call

```
calc.add(3,2);
calc.getMem();
```

I receive the desired result.

Obviously I was missing the this so I changed my getMem to

```
getMem: function(){
    return this.mem;
}
```

My Question is: Why does it work in the inital state (without this) when I first call add?

Comment: Thanks for alle the answer, I will use strict mode from now on to prevent such issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `cal.add` you are creating a global variable `mem`. So it seems like it works because `getMem` is then trying to access that global. But it is probably not what you want. If you call `getMem()` before `add()` it is still trying to access the global `mem`, but it hasn't been defined yet, hence the error.

```js
var calc = {
  getMem: function(){
      return mem;
  },

  mem:0,

  add: function (a,b){
      mem =  a*b;
      return a*b;
  },
}
calc.add(2, 4)
console.log(mem) // available globally
```

Comment: Damn it, I guess this is why one should use strict mode.

Comment: Ha @Vanice -- yes, I think everyone becomes convinced of strict mode by something like this.

Comment: When you come with a C# background to JS you expect this member behavior of "objects" :)

Answer (score 2):

`calc` is not a class, this is not how you set values of an object, if you add a console.log() inside off `add` you can see, that `mem` is undefined there, so the line

```
mem =  a*b;
```

sets a global variable named `mem` to `a*b`, instead of a local value,

```js
calc = {
    getMem: function(){
        return mem;
    },

    mem:0,

    add: function (a,b){
 console.log(mem)
        mem =  a*b;
        return a*b;
    },
}

calc.add(0,0)
```

You have to set it with `this.mem`:

```js
"use strict";    

const calc = {
    getMem: function(){
        return this.mem;
    },

    mem:0,

    add: function (a,b){
        this.mem =  a*b;
        return a*b;
    },
}

calc.add(2,3)
console.log(calc.getMem())
```

And also return `this.mem` in the getMem function

Answer (score 1):

When you call your function `getMem()` it is unable to find any local or global variable with the name `mem` that is why you get a reference error. When you execute your `add()` function it creates a variable `mem` in the global scope, so now when you call `getMem()` global variable `mem` is being returned.

Execute the program in `strict` mode and you will get reference error.

```js
"use strict"
var calc = {
  getMem: function(){
      return mem;
  },

  mem:0,

  add: function (a,b){
      mem =  a*b;
      return a*b;
  },
}
calc.add(2, 4)
console.log(mem)
```